# How can you create a unique serial number for a given string?

Tags: java, unique, factory

So I am trying to create a class that represents a fictional Licence Number for a given person. The Licence Number is constructed from the following:

- The initials of the person's forename and surname
- The year the licence was issued
- A random arbitrary serial number

So for example, Maggie Smith whose licence was issued in 1990, might have a Licence Number of MS-1990-11, with 11 being the serial number. However, Mark Sanders might have had his licence issued the same year meaning the beginning of his licence may be MS-1990 also.

So this is where the problem occurs. I need to make sure that the serial number for this person is not the same as Maggie's. So I'd have to check through any records that have the same initials and issue year, then generate a new unique serial number. Here's my code so far:

```
public class LicenceNumber {

private final Name driverName;
private final Date issueDate;
private static final Map<String, LicenceNumber> LICENCENOS = new HashMap<String, LicenceNumber>();

public LicenceNumber(Name driverName, Date issueDate){

    this.driverName = driverName;
    this.issueDate = issueDate;
}

public static LicenceNumber getInstance(Name driverName, Date issueDate){
    Calendar tempCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    tempCal.setTime(issueDate);
    String issueYear = String.valueOf(tempCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    int serialNo = 1;
    String k = driverName.getForename().substring(0, 1) + driverName.getSurname().substring(0, 1) + "-" + issueYear + "-" + serialNo;

    if(!LICENCENOS.containsKey(k)){
        LICENCENOS.put(k, new LicenceNumber(driverName,issueDate));
    }

    return LICENCENOS.get(k);
}

public boolean isUnique(){
    return true;
}

public Name getDriverName() {
    return driverName;
}

public Date getIssueDate() {
    return issueDate;
}
}
```

And a snippet of how it may be instantiated:

```
public final class DrivingLicence {

private final Name driverName;
private final Date driverDOB;
private final Date issueDate;
private final LicenceNumber licenceNo;
private final boolean isFull;

public DrivingLicence(Name driverName, Date driverDOB, Date issueDate, boolean isFull){
    //TO-DO validate inputs
    this.driverName = driverName;
    this.driverDOB = driverDOB;
    this.issueDate = issueDate;
    this.licenceNo = LicenceNumber.getInstance(driverName, issueDate);
    //this.licenceNo = new LicenceNumber(driverName, issueDate);//instantiate a licence number using the driverName and dateOfIssue
    this.isFull = isFull;
}
}
```

I've based it on some lecture notes that discuss how you can use factories for uniqueness. I'm also unsure if I should create a LicenceNumber using getInstance or by creating a new Object. Does anyone know a way I could check if a serial number for a given string, e.g. XX-XXXX already exists?

Comment: Is this backed by a database at all? I mean, what constitutes "existence" -- over what time frame?

Comment: No there's no database involved. If I've implemented it correctly, the LicenceNumbers are stored in the Map, so I'd have to check there.

Comment: I would suggest an AtomicInteger. I will provide a quick answer in just a moment.

Comment: You will need to be careful about threading issues.  Also, if you don't worry about "gaps" in sequence numbers for MS-1980, you could have one master sequence generator.  Otherwise you would need a sequence generator for each set of initials and year.

Comment: @MarkStewart Could you elaborate on "gaps"? Do you mean the dashes between components of LicenceNumber? If so, then unfortunately I need them.

Comment: Why do they have to be random? Why not just a sequential series?

Comment: @FredK I could just store a serial number variable and have it increment by one each time a new LicenceNo is created. That way if Mark was generated after molly, then the number would be unique. But I think it makes more sense that if someone has the same initials, then their serial number should just be one greater than the previous.

Comment: By gaps, I mean is it okay if for all the M* S*  born in 1990, is it okay if the sequential number has gaps:  MS-1980-11, MS-1980-12, MS-1980-15, MS-1980-20:  gaps are 13, 14, 16 through 20.  If that kind of gap is okay, then you could have a master sequence generator for all initials and years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that will create incremental numbers for the *duration of the program*. Since there is no backing database, each run of the program will reset.

It works by using an `AtomicInteger` to ensure uniqueness. I have used a `ConcurrentMap` to take advantage of thread safety as well as the `.putIfAbsent` method. However, it can be easily converted to use a standard `Map`. I also just used a `String`, but a better approach would be to use a real domain object. It is sufficient for handling the OP's question and for illustrative purposes.

```
// a Map for holding the sequencing
private ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> _sequence = 
        new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

/**
 * Returns a unique, incrementing sequence, formatted to
 * 0 prefixed, 3 places, based upon the User's initials
 * and the registration year
 */
public String getSequence(String initials, String year)
{
    String key = makePrefix(initials, year);
    AtomicInteger chk = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicInteger ai = _sequence.putIfAbsent(key, chk);
    if (ai == null) {
        ai = chk;
    }

    int val = ai.incrementAndGet();

    String fmt = String.format("%03d", val);

    return fmt;
}

/**
 * A helper method to make the prefix, which is the
 * concatintion of the initials, a "-", and a year.
 */
private String makePrefix (String initials, String year)
{
    return initials + "-" + year;
}
```

Test Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LicensePlate_37169055 lp = new LicensePlate_37169055();
    System.out.println("ko, 1999: " + lp.getSequence("ko", "1999"));
    System.out.println("ac, 1999: " + lp.getSequence("ac", "1999"));
    System.out.println("ko, 1999: " + lp.getSequence("ko", "1999"));
    System.out.println("ac, 1999: " + lp.getSequence("ac", "1999"));
    System.out.println("ms, 1999: " + lp.getSequence("ms", "1999"));
    System.out.println("ko, 2001: " + lp.getSequence("ko", "2001"));

}
```

Example Output:

> ko, 1999: 001
>   ac, 1999: 001
>   ko, 1999: 002
>   ac, 1999: 002
>   ms, 1999: 001
>   ko, 2001: 001

To integrate into the OP's code, the following modifications are suggestive:

```
public static LicenceNumber getInstance(Name driverName, Date issueDate){
  Calendar tempCal = Calendar.getInstance();
  tempCal.setTime(issueDate);
  String issueYear = String.valueOf(tempCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

  // ** get the initials; I would actually move this functionality to be
  //   a method on the Name class
  String initials = driverName.getForename().substring(0, 1) + driverName.getSurname().substring(0, 1);

  // get the unique serial number
  String serial = getSequence(initials, issueYear);

  // make the full licenseplate String
  String k = makePrefix(initials, issueYear) + "-" + serial;

if(!LICENCENOS.containsKey(k)){
    LICENCENOS.put(k, new LicenceNumber(driverName,issueDate));
}

return LICENCENOS.get(k);
```

}

Comment: It appears that when setting the serialNumber using getSequence(), I'm getting an error saying getSequence should be static. Also, how could this be implemented using a standard Map?

Comment: Sorry, missed that `getInstance()` is static (related question: why is it?). So, the other methods need to be static as well. To use a standard `Map<>`, remove the Concurrent from them, and then change from `putIfAbsent` to something akin to  `ai = _sequence.get(key); if (ai == null) { ai = chk; _sequence.put(key, ai);}`. Basically if you read the Javadoc for `putIfAbsent` it gives the algorithm it is using. Note that making these changes removes thread safety.

Comment: My bad, the standard `Map` has a `putIfAbsent()`, so in theory you can just change from `ConcurrentMap`/`CurrentHashMap` to `Map`/`HashMap`: `static final private Map<String, AtomicInteger> _sequence =  new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Ah yeah that works perfectly. The reason I've made getInstance static is because I'm basing it on an example given in some lecture notes. Is there a reason it shouldn't be?

Comment: Glad the answer helped! IMHO, `getInstance()` implies a Singleton pattern; I would expect `getInstance()` to return some singleton, not a particular instantiation of an object. If I follow the idea, basically you have a builder approach, rather than using a constructor. The approach works, but I would push for a refactoring in a code review because too many methods and variables must be static, yet the constructor for `LicenseNumber` is public. The implication is that I can do `new LicenseNumber()`, but it is not going to be properly registered in the ` LICENCENOS` map.

Comment: Ok so in the spec for this, one of the aims is to, "demonstrate the use of factories to control instantiation of objects, including guaranteeing the
instantiation of unique instances". And in my lecture notes, there's a section on "using a factory for uniqueness", so I made the connection and assumed that this would be the best way to do it. However, in a short example on how to implement a DrivingLicence class, one of the comments under the constructor is, "// instantiate a licence number using the driverName and dateOfIssue". Now the fact it says "instantiate" makes me think (part1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111674/discussion-between-andrew-coates-and-kevino).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrintOddEvenMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        OddEvenRunnable oddRunnable=new OddEvenRunnable(1);
        OddEvenRunnable evenRunnable=new OddEvenRunnable(0);
 
        Thread t1=new Thread(oddRunnable,"Odd");
        Thread t2=new Thread(evenRunnable,"Even");
 
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
 
    }
}
```